only the year is clickable, using biblatex
From this code:
\usepackage[style=authoryear, maxcitenames=1, uniquelist=false, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib} % adjust this to the name of your .bib file
\AtEveryCite{\ifnameundef{labelname}
  {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
  {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
  
    \printnames[first-last]{labelname}%
    \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=1}
      {}
      {\printtext{ et al.}}%
    \addspace\printfield{year}%
  }}
  }

Only the year is clickable, why ?


because if you cite two works of the author, you would get Asai et al. 2022, 2024  and then it is unclear to which of both works the author should link.

@UlrikeFischer sorry but where do you see I cite two works ?

you don't. But it is possible, and the code has to handle this option.
